# Change border color text input When its empty in react native

Tags: react-native

I want when text input is empty change border color to red with press button:

```
const post = () => {

  
   let list = [];

    if (homeAge === '') {
        list.push('homeage')
    }
}
```

```
    <TextInput
        style={[Styles.TextInput, { borderColor: list.includes('homeage') ? 'red' : '#006d41' }]}
                            onChangeText={(event) => homeAgeHandler(event)}
           />
```

```
<Button style={Styles.Button}
                        onPress={() => post()}>
                        <Text style={Styles.TextButton}>ثبت اطلاعات</Text>
                    </Button>
```

Comment: I think you need a `borderWidth` on there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a useRef hook :

```
const ref=useRef(0);
const post = () => {

  
   let list = [];

    if (homeAge === '') {
        list.push('homeage')
    }
}

useEffect(()=>{
if(list.size==0&&ref.current)
{
  ref.current.style.borderColor = "red";
}
},[list,ref]);
<TextInput ref={ref}
        
                            onChangeText={(event) => homeAgeHandler(event)}
           />
<Button style={Styles.Button}
                        onPress={() => post()}>
                        <Text style={Styles.TextButton}>ثبت اطلاعات</Text>
                    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example to validate text and change styling based on validation,

```
const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const validateText = () => {
    if (text === "") {
      setError(true);
    } else {
      setError(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput style={[Styles.TextInput, { borderColor: error ? 'red' : '#006d41', borderWidth:'1px'}]}
        onChangeText={setText}
       />

      <Button style={Styles.Button}
         onPress={validateText}>
         <Text style={Styles.TextButton}>ثبت اطلاعات</Text>
      </Button>

     
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

TextInput empty:

[image]

TextInput not empty:

[image]

Use state instead.

Also, In the given example, you are trying to access the `list` which is the local variable of the `post()` method.

Here is the alternate solution:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [homeAge, setHomeAge] = useState('');

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        value={homeAge}
        style={[
          styles.textInput,
          { borderColor: !homeAge ? 'red' : '#006d41' },
        ]}
        onChangeText={(text) => setHomeAge(text)}
      />
      <Button title={'ثبت اطلاعات'} style={styles.button} onPress={() => {}} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  textInput: {
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});
```

Working example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/arrogant-peanut)